# PyGTK - localization with Right To Left languages (BiDi)

Tags: localization, gtk, pygtk, arabic, hebrew

(Almost?) all of the material in the Web regarding PyGTK localization is discussing usage of `gettext` - i.e., how to properly show the translated strings.

But that's not enough... There are certain languages (Hebrew, Arabic and more) that are written from Right To Left, and therefore, the widgets should be 'swapped'. Packing 'Start' should be at the rightmost, and continue to the left.

I assume that `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')` should solve the problem.
However, it didn't work (on Hebrew Windows 7 machine).

Here is a sample code, that tries to change the locale to Hebrew and displays 2 buttons - but they are still from Left To Right:

```
import gtk
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'Hebrew_Israel.1255')
print locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL)

window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
window.connect("destroy", lambda w: gtk.main_quit())

box1 = gtk.HBox(False, 0)
window.add(box1)

button1 = gtk.Button("first")
box1.pack_start(button1, True, True, 0)

button2 = gtk.Button("second")
box1.pack_start(button2, True, True, 0)

window.show_all()
gtk.main()
```

Comment: It's amazing how easy is to do it with PySide (and how easy to find the solution in the QT world...): `QtGui.QApplication.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LayoutDirection.RightToLeft)`

Comment: `box1.set_direction(gtk.TEXT_DIR_RTL)` works for that simple example. But the property doesn't appear to be inherited in nested containers. Hmmm...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`gtk.widget_set_default_direction`](http://pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/class-gtkwidget.html#function-gtk--widget-set-default-direction)`(gtk.TEXT_DIR_RTL)`

This sets the default direction for widgets that don't call `set_direction`.

Comment: Works great, even with `gtk.Builder`, which currently ignores my `get_translation_domain` for strings translations. Thanks